# Passing a list of servlet values

Tags: java, servlets

Using apache poi, I am reading the first row values of an excel file like this

```
try
{
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
for (int i =0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++)
{
   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
   Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

   String SheetName = "<span class='blue'><b>" +sheet.getSheetName()+ "<b></span><br>";
       request.setAttribute("SheetName", SheetName);
   Row row = rowIterator.next();
      if(row.getRowNum() == 0) 
    { 
       Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
       while(cellIterator.hasNext()) 
         {
        Cell cell1 = cellIterator.next();

        switch(cell1.getCellType()) 
           {
             case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
             String strval = cell1.getStringCellValue();
             request.setAttribute("Values2", strval);
             break;
           }
                      }
             }
        }
            file.close();
    }catch(NoSuchElementException e)
    {}
```

Now, I want to pass a list of values the `strval` is only sending one value, how do I sent many values??
How to send an array of items to my jsp page?

Comment: How about concanitate all values to one string ansd using an unique letter -or more- as a seperator. With `splitAll()` will it be easy to restore the original values.

Comment: @reporter ... That sounds horrible, why wouldn't you just pass a collection?

Comment: How to send a list or array of items? By sending a list or array of items, the same way you pass a string now.

Comment: @DaveNewton As he wrote he want to send all values with one parameter (or attribute). This is one way that works. I haven't written that is the best way ;-)

Comment: @reporter "I want to pass a list of values, how do I send many values?" That said, passing a list *IS* passing one parameter/attributes, a list. There is no way this question can be misinterpreted.

Comment: Oh than I read the sentence wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send `List` as an attribute value. For example:

```
List<String> cellValues = new ArrayList<String>();
while(cellIterator.hasNext()) 
     {
    Cell cell1 = cellIterator.next();

    switch(cell1.getCellType()) 
       {
         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
         String strval = cell1.getStringCellValue();
         cellValues.add(strval);
         break;
       }
                  }
         }
    }
request.settAttribute("Values2", cellValues);
```